# How to type geographical coordinates in LaTeX tables?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to type geographical coordinate such as:

```
N 52° 58.110'
E 00° 40.070'
```

in table. Please excuse me for that I have start leaning about LaTeX just three weeks ago.
I would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned 'in table'. Do you mean you are interested in a way to write these in to a table, or that you want to have the degrees, minutes and seconds in separate columns of a table?

Answer (score 20):

There are several options. The `siunitx` package provides an `\ang` command that typesets angles. Degrees, minutes and seconds should be separated by semi colons. Alternatively you can set the numbers in math-mode (`$ ... $`), and use `^\circ` for the degree sign and `'` or `^\prime` for the minute mark.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
N\ang{52;58.110;} E\ang{00;40.070;}

N$52^\circ 58.110'$ E$00^\circ 40.070^\prime$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
N $52^\circ$ $58.110'$ E $00^\circ$ $40.070'$
```

Tabular is meaningless here. Spaces are according to your request.
You can make your own macro, e.g. (spacing changed):

```
\def\nswe#1#2#3{#1\,$#2^\circ\,#3'$}
```

Usage: `\nswe{N}{52}{58.110}`.

Answer (score 6):

`\usepackage{gensymb}` - provides the `\degree` symbol

```
$32\degree59'59.8''S 148\degree15'44.3''E$
```

shows as:

[image]